# understanding higher direct images of $\mathbb{G}_m$ for a finite Galois map

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $\mu_r$ denote the group of $r$-th roots of unity, and moreover suppose $\mu_r$ (algebraically) acts on $X$ freely. Then $Y:= X/\mu_r$ is also a smooth quasi-projective variety, and the projection $\pi: X\rightarrow Y$ is an finite etale morphism.

I am interested in understanding the sheaves $R^i\pi_*\mathbb{G}_m$ and their cohomologies $H^j_{et}(Y,R^i\pi_*\mathbb{G}_m)$ for small $i,j$ (0\leq i,j\leq 2). Can these be concretely described?

If the fibers were connected, then I know some results for these sheaves and their cohomologies. But I'm facing trouble as the fiber is discrete in my case.

In general, is there a good reference for these groups (I've looked at Milne, but don't seem to find it.) Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The etale higher direct images for a finite morphism are zero.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger : Can you please suggest some reference? Also, can something be said about the direct image $\pi_*\mathbb{G}_m$?

Comment: Milne, Etale Cohomology, II, Corollary 3.6.